# RNSound.IsAndroid error when trying to play sound

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, audio, aws-amplify, react-native-sound

I recently got into `react-native` and after connecting it to my aws database and ... I have been trying to play some audios I had stored in my bucket. For this I tried using `react-native-sound` but once i import it I get the error

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNSound.IsAndroid')
```

which seems to be a common problem when using this package. Now I have tried a couple of solutions listed under the following link

https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/issues/592

and now I think that my react-native link doesn't work right cuz when I use it i get the following result

```
PS C:\HealthProject\TestPackage> react-native link react-native-sound
PS C:\HealthProject\TestPackage>
```

also I don't have an android nor ios folder to perform a manual installation I only have the folders that were generated by expo.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what is your react-native version ?

Comment: 0.60 is my current version

Comment: I have the same problem